# How to identify change in dummy variable within timeframe?

Tags: python, replace

I have a dataset like this. I hope to identify the change in 'type' (dummy variable) by 'id' **within** a year. And then I want to create a new category under 'type' called 'c', and assign 'c' to this row when such changes are detected. For example, person 2 has changed its type from 'y' to 'n' within 2020. Then, I hope to replace 'y' and 'n' in row 2 and 3 with 'c' in each row. I only want to identify changes within the year, so Person 1's type changes over the year (first and last rows) will not influence its current value. Person 3 and 4's types should remain the same as well.

I am quite new to python. Thank you for your help!

| year | type | person id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | y | 1 |
| 2020 | y | 2 |
| 2020 | n | 2 |
| 2021 | y | 3 |
| 2021 | n | 4 |
| 2021 | n | 1 |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
changes_df = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['person id', 'year']).count().rename({'type': 'counts'}, axis=1).reset_index()
```

That will give you the number of different rows for every person and year combination. And then:

```
df = df.merge(changes_df, how='left')
df.loc[df['counts'] > 1, 'type'] = 'c'
df.drop('counts', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

That will change the type of every combination that has two types to 'c'.